# Referencing Category Description in Wordpress php

Tags: php, wordpress, image, categories

I'm trying to set up a WordPress "Categories Images" plugin that allows adding custom icons to WP Categories and displays them on a page. In order to display the icons there is a specific code:

```
<?php foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php
$attr = array(
'class' => 'category_image',
'alt' => 'image alt',
'height' => 25,
'width' => 25,
'title' => 'category_description',
);
z_taxonomy_image($cat->term_id, 'full', $attr); ?></a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

That code works, I get what I need - small icons for each category a page has, but I also want to display a category description text on hover. Right now it displays "category_description" placeholder text on hover, which you can see is specified in 'title' line. And unfortunately I lack any php knowledge to get that reference right. 
I found this link that explains how to call for category description,

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description

but I have no idea how to insert it into the code above so it could reference everything as needed. Maybe anyone knows how to implement that reference in code, it would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work. Used name as a title for the link and used a description call to add a custom link to the icon.

```
<?php foreach (get_the_category() as $cat) : ?>

<a href="<?php echo category_description( $cat ); ?>" title="<?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?>"> 

<?php
$attr = array(
'class' => 'category_image',
'alt' => 'image alt',
'height' => 25,
'width' => 25,

);
z_taxonomy_image($cat->term_id, 'full', $attr); ?>

</a>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```